# Outlook 2010 where is the default location when saving emails

Tags: windows-7, outlook-2010

In Outlook 2010, open up an email > File > Save. Where is Outlook saving the email to? I didn't see it in "My Documents" folder (as File > Save As, default save to that folder). Searching online only found how to change the default location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default location is

Libraries\Documents